# App engine warmup request not working for endpoints

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-endpoints, google-app-engine

I have android client and google app engine java server. Even though I see the warmup requests, first request (or 2-3 requests sometimes) to my endpoint takes extremely long time (8 - 20 seconds or even more).

It is quite annoying because the other instance (I have 1 resident instance and I'm the only user clicking there, requests take 100-200ms and I send 1-3 requests per seconds) could serve this request in ~500ms, but instead it spawns new instance, makes a warmup request and sends the request to the new instance (even though I set min_pending_latency = 10000). Example:

```
I 2014-12-09 18:39:51.438 200 0 B 3657ms /_ah/warmup
I 2014-12-09 18:39:55.649 200 7.7 KB 8673ms /_ah/spi/com.sth.MyEndpoint.getMyEntity
I 2014-12-09 18:40:15.349 200 7.7 KB 9081ms /_ah/spi/com.sth.MyEndpoint.getMyEntity
I 2014-12-09 18:43:17.328 200 7.7 KB 135ms /_ah/spi/com.sth.MyEndpoint.getMyEntity
```

I don't want my users to randomly have delays in tens of seconds. I read the page:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Java_appengine_web_xml_Warmup_requests
There is something about "Using a custom warmup servlet" but I still don't know how could I warmup the endpoint... If the answer is there indeed, please point it out to me, tell me *exactly* what should I do...

Anyone here found a solution for it? Meaning, I want my new instance to start processing requests after it initiates the Endpoint, so it will serve first incomming request from real user in normal time, like the usual 100 - 200 ms (or at least under 1sec). How do I do that?
Please, help ! :)

[edit]

my web.xml (mb it helps):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?><web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.5" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<servlet>
<servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
<init-param>
 <param-name>services</param-name>
 <param-value>com.sth.MyEndpoint</param-value>
</init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>  
<servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/_ah/spi/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

[edit]
And my appengine-web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
<application>myappname</application>
<version>version4</version>
<threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
<precompilation-enabled>true</precompilation-enabled>
<!-- Configure java.util.logging -->
<system-properties>
    <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties" />
</system-properties>
<automatic-scaling>
    <min-idle-instances>1</min-idle-instances>
    <max-idle-instances>1</max-idle-instances>
    <min-pending-latency>10.0s</min-pending-latency>
    <max-pending-latency>15.0s</max-pending-latency>
</automatic-scaling>
<warmup-requests-enabled>true</warmup-requests-enabled>
</appengine-web-app>
```

Comment: Please, help? It's killing me. Here's the example, I do some request 3 times, 2x its <200ms, 3rd it spins new instance and waits for total of 15 seconds, and it could be served in the regular ~200ms on first instance:
`I 2014-12-14 22:05:46.901 200 361 B 184ms /_ah/spi/com.sth.MyEndpoint.attack
 I 2014-12-14 22:05:58.530 200 409 B 182ms /_ah/spi/com.sth.MyEndpoint.attack
 I 2014-12-14 22:06:02.638 200 0 B 4129ms /_ah/warmup
 I 2014-12-14 22:06:22.058 200 367 B 11220ms /_ah/spi/com.sth.MyEndpoint.attack`

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to write out a detailed trace of the events that happen on your system when these requests occur, and I hope that it clears up where the issue lies. Notice that the timestamps on the request logs are telling you when the request *response* was sent from the app, so I'm going to refer to the times when the requests were *received* at the app by subtracting their run-time (the `ms` field of the log line)

- **Your first request** is received at `22:05:46.717` (we'll call this `T + 0` seconds)
- You have `min_idle_instances` set to 1 and `max_idle_instances` also set
  to 1, so at any given time the system can only have 1 idle instance
  waiting for requests. When this first request is received, it sends
  it to that instance that was spun up a long time ago, and was idly
  waiting, just waiting to serve somebody. "Instance 1" (as we'll call it) happily returns the
  response in `184 ms`
- **Your second request** is received at `22:05:58.121` (`T + 12` seconds approx)

  (This second request is also routed to the only serving instance - Instance 1. It returns the response in `182 ms`)
- As soon as the App Master (the part of the system that manages
  scaling and instances based on your config and request load)
  determines Instance 1 is not idle, it sends a warm-up request
  to the new instance ("Instance 2") to tell it to get ready.
- **The warm-up request to Instance 2** is received at `22:05:58.509` (`T + 12` seconds approx)
- Depending on how much work needs to be done to spin up your instance and get it ready to serve, it will take a shorter or longer time *after* this warm-up request is received for Instance 2 to actually be serving. The fact that you have specified `<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>` for the system service servlet means that it will also load the Endpoints SystemServiceServlet by invoking its `init` method. This will further increase the time before the instance is serving.

  (Note that the warm-up request took 4.129 seconds to respond)
- **The third request** is received at `22:06:10.838` (`T + 24` seconds approx)

  (Note that this request is received around 12 seconds after Instance 2 has received its warm-up request, or around 8 seconds after the warm-up request actually responded, which is when Instance 2 powered on).

  The fact that you have defined `minimum_pending_latency = 10.0s` would usually mean that when a request is received for which the app master determines there is no free instance ready to serve, the request will wait a *minimum* of `10.0s` (and according to your the maximum, a *maximum* of `15.0s`) before checking for a free instance to be available. The fact that you've defined `minimum_idle_instances`, however, [according to the docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/performancesettings#Setting_the_Pending_Latency), means that `minimum_pending_latency` should have "less effect on your apps' performance"...

---

This is all the information that the logs you provided show us. I can't be sure without seeing more code what exactly happened (for example, whether your instances will take a short or long time to spin up based on the amount of jar files you are including), but it appears to be a consequence of the combination of features you used. Perhaps the third request was put in the pending queue, waited 11 seconds (above 10 and below 15), and finally got served by either of the instances (did you see a spin-down request on either of the instances, given that you defined a 1-idle-instance max?), taking the remaining `~200 ms` to actually process the API call, which is consistent with the latency on the first two requests.

I think if you play with the settings you have, given what you now can visualize about the request load's impact on scaling, you might see this latency disappear.

Comment: Thanks for checking out my topic. From 22:05 (T - 45 seconds) till 22:07 (T + 62 seconds), this was all the traffic of my application - these 3 requests and a warmup. I can't understand why the third request waited between 10 and 15 seconds while I have one instance always on, and I had no traffic, and my code runs in <200ms as you can see. I have total of 17 jars, 5 are appengine-..., 5 are datanucleus-..., gcm-server.jar, geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec-1.0.jar, jdo-api-3.0.1.jar, json-simple-1.1.jar, jsr107cache-1.1.jar, jta-1.1.jar, asm-4.0.jar